# android flying picture animation

Tags: android, animation

I'd like to create a picture animation, say, a circle (which is an imageView) flying across the screen inside a designated area. Not just disappearing and reappearing at some other position, but moving smoothly across the screen. Can someone give me some basic ideas how to implement that?

Comment: have a look at API demos http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use frame animation.

Like:

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>
<animation-list xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”id=”selected”
 android:oneshot=”false”>        
 <item android:drawable=”@drawable/ball1″ android:duration=”50″ />
 <item android:drawable=”@drawable/ball2″ android:duration=”50″ />
 <item android:drawable=”@drawable/ball3″ android:duration=”50″ />
 <item android:drawable=”@drawable/ball4″ android:duration=”50″ />
 <item android:drawable=”@drawable/ball5″ android:duration=”50″ />
 <item android:drawable=”@drawable/ball6″ android:duration=”50″ />
</animation-list>
```

You can have the images/ bitmaps drawn and use it as a frame and set the time period and the positions according to your requirement. You can use interpolators to give the required effect. There are many a types of interpolators available. You can use the desired interpolator according to your requirement.